# Osmdroid - open zipped tiles from ZIP?

Tags: android, zip, osmdroid

my tiles from Offline maps are increasing max allowed number of files in ZIP (65535 files), so I am thinking of Zipping some files.

OSMdroid Mapnik format has format X/Y/tile.png.Where X is the zoom and Y is colums, where tile is rows in map in desired zoom. I am thinking of zipping X or Y's and then zipping it together to one ZIP file. Problem is, Osmdroid mapView doesn't see my tiles, when they are inside ZIP files. Do you know, in which class OSMdroid handles opening tiles? I think I may have to change this behavior in code. Have you faced some problem? Or is there any simple way how can mapView see zipped images in ZIP?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Zip file and it increased the size limitation, just unzip file and split it to two or more zip files. To do this you can move some zoom levels tiles to other zip file.
I had the same problem and solved this by moving tiles for zoom levels 16 to 18 in another file. 
But I think in small devices it is better to use unzipped tiles. It may increase speed more than 10 times.

Comment: I also separate tiles on several zips and it works perfectly. You can separate zoom levels, or even one zoom level is different zips and have several zips for different tile sources without problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use sqlite. It's faster and there's no size limits.

https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/master/osmdroid-android/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/tileprovider/modules/ZipFileArchive.java

more archive providers are here
https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/tree/master/osmdroid-android/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/tileprovider/modules

I don't think the limitation is an osmdroid specific thing. I think it's a java and/or android limitation based on the way osmdroid opens the files and looks through the TOC for a specific file.